# Golang Type system inconsistency (http package)

Tags: go, types, interface

I am trying to wrap my head around the GoLang type system, and there area a few things the confuse me.

So I have been working on the http library to try to understand this and I have come across the following that makes no sense.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "io"
)

func convert(closer io.Closer) ([]byte) {
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(closer);
    return body
}

func main() {

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com", nil)

    response, _ := client.Do(req);

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    fmt.Println(body);
    fmt.Println(convert(response.Body))

}
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ctTcATFiPv)

this is not about the fact that the convert function is not needed it is the fact that the response body is of type io.closer and the ioutil.Readall takes a io.reader, yet I can pass it in, in one instance but not if in another. Is there something that I am missing that is magically happening.

I know that the closer technically passes the reader interface as it implements the the Read method but that should be true in both the function and the main body.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want `convert` to accept `io.Closer` if it should be `io.Reader`?

Comment: `is the fact that the response body is of type io.closer`... https://golang.org/src/net/http/response.go The body of a Response is of type `io.ReadCloser`.

Comment: Sorry I made a liitle mistake here, the default type of the http body is io.ReadCloser this is from the main package https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is the fact that the response body is of type io.closer

No, it is not. Declaration of `Request.Body` is at [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

```
Body io.ReadCloser
```

The `Request.Body` field is of type [`io.ReadCloser`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadCloser), it is both an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) and an [`io.Closer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer).

Since it is an `io.Reader` (dynamic value of `Request.Body` implements `io.Reader`), you may use / pass it where an `io.Reader` is required, e.g. to [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll).

Since it also implements `io.Closer`, you can also pass it where `io.Closer` is required, like your `convert()` function.

But inside convert the `closer` param has static type `io.Closer`, you can't use `closer` where an `in.Reader` is required. It might be (and in your case it is) that the dynamic type stored in `closer` also implements `io.Reader`, but there is no guarantee for this. Like in this example:

```
type mycloser int

func (mycloser) Close() error { return nil }

func main() {
    var m io.Closer = mycloser(0)
    convert(m)
}
```

In the above example `closer` inside `convert()` will hold a value of type `mycloser`, which truly does not implement `io.Reader`.

If your `convert()` function intends to treat its parameter also as an `io.Reader`, the parameter type should be `io.ReadCloser`:

```
func convert(rc io.ReadCloser) ([]byte, error) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rc)
    if err != nil {
        return body, err
    }
    err = rc.Close()
    return body, err
}
```